# Управление контентом на сайте с express js

Tags: веб-программирование, node.js, express

Задача заключается в том, что уже имеется работающее приложение на express js, главная страница - информационный лендинг. Так вот на этой главной странице требуется управлять контентом, а именно иметь возможность добавлять статьи, фотографии в галерею и т.п., т.е. как в обычной cms. Есть ли какой-то способ это сделать без написания велосипедов в виде своей cms?

Comment: Переписать все с использованием CMS не думали? Если CMS даже на node.js =)

Comment: Других вариантов нет?(

Comment: Либо писать CMS, либо переписывать полсайта с существующей. Нет, т.к. в итоге вы хотите CMS, других вариантов нет.

Comment: Я думал, может как-то вынести только главную страницу на cms, а остальное оставить в экспрессе. Придется, конечно, запускать 2 приложения вместо одного и не понятно как быть с сессией...да и с роутами, ведь будут 2 разных порта.